# $X\cup Y$ is satisfiable iff for every finite $W \subseteq X$, $W\cup Y$ is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

> Let $X,Y$ be sets of propositions. Prove that $X∪Y$ is satisfiable iff
> for every finite $W⊆X$, $W∪Y$ is satisfiable.
>
> Assume $X∪Y$ is satisfiable. Then every subset of X∪Y is satisfiable,
> in particular for every finite $W⊆X$, as $W∪Y⊆X∪Y$, $W∪Y$ is
> satisfiable.

This is my attempt to prove it, I wanted to check if it makes sense and what I can improve upon..

First direction is trivial.

Assume for every finite $W⊆X$, $W∪Y$ is satisfiable. Assume towards contradiction $X∪Y$ is not satisfiable. Then $X∪Y$ is not finitely satisfiable and there exists $X'=\left\{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}\right\}\, Y'=\left\{y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{m}\right\}$ such that X'∪Y' is not satisfiable. As $W∪Y$ is satisfiable, $Y$ is satisfiable and therefore $Y'$ is also satisfiable, then $X'$ must not be satisfiable. But by our assumption $X'∪Y$ must be satisfiable, and in particular $X'$ must be satisfiable. Contradiction!

Comment: You need to take $W$ to be equal to $X'$. Apart from that, it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the following is more straightforward.

Assume $X\cup Y$ is not satisfiable. We need to show for some finite $W \subseteq X, W\cup Y $ is not satisfiable (*).

Since $X\cup Y$ is not sat., there are finite $X^\prime\subseteq X$ and $Y^\prime\subseteq Y$ such that $X^\prime \cup Y^\prime$ is not satisfiable. Because $X^\prime \cup Y^\prime$ is not satisfiable, $X^\prime \cup Y$ is not satisfiable. So $X^\prime\subseteq X, X^\prime \cup Y$ is not satisfiable. This means (*).

Comment: What condition do you mean? I agree it is essentially the same with the question, though. I tried $\neg P \to \neg Q$ instead of $Q\to P$.

Comment: I corrected it.